# UITableViewCell var "table view cell" was never mutated

Tags: ios, swift, sdk

In swift 2.0 when I tried to make var object of UITableViewCell custom class, swift is suggesting me to convert it to "let" because object was never mutated.

I have a UIButton on UITableViewCell but it is renamed to ABC on touchupinside method call of the button if  i make its object to "let"

Refer to following piece of code:

```
var nameCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(nameCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) 

switch indexpath.row{
case 0:
     nameCell.customButton.titleLabel!.text = "ABC"
case 1:
     nameCell.customButton.titleLabel!.text = "DEF"
case 2:
     nameCell.customButton.titleLabel!.text = "GHI"
}

return nameCell
```

result:

### var nameCell was never mutated convert it to let

Comment: use let instead var like `let nameCell`

Comment: but if i use 'let' the `UIButton` always return its `title` as "ABC" in its `touchUpInside` method call

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
nameCell.customButton.setTitle("ABC", forState: .Normal)
```

instead of

```
nameCell.customButton.titleLabel!.text = "ABC"
```

and change `var` to `let` in

```
var nameCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(nameCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

Comment: Thanks @UditS I was about to post the same. I just resolved it as `titleLabel.text` is a `{ get }` property of swift, need to `setTitle` property, but its strange that i didn't get any warning that i can't set the get property from swift

Comment: Same behavior is in ObjC. Since you are trying to set  `titleLabel.text` which is not a { get } (readonly) property for a label, it does not give any error. On the other hand, if you try to set something to `titleLabel`, such as `titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 10))`, it does give an error.